# Gatsby Build fails on Netlify by works locally. Ffmpeg dependency issue

Tags: ffmpeg, web-deployment, gatsby, netlify

I'm trying to deploy my site on Netlify, and the `gatsby build` command works perfectly fine on my system. But when I run in on Netlify, I run into the issue shown below.

Unhandled rejection: cannot find ffprobe seems to be the issue. I think it's because I have ffmpeg installed on my system (macOS) but there is no installation procedure during the build process in Netlify. Can somebody please guide me as to what I can do to fix this?

```
1:19:18 AM: info bootstrap finished - 5.299 s
1:19:18 AM: ⠀
1:19:22 AM: error UNHANDLED REJECTION Cannot find ffprobe
1:19:23 AM: 
1:19:23 AM:   Error: Cannot find ffprobe
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - ffprobe.js:145 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[fluent-ffmpeg]/lib/ffprobe.js:145:31
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - capabilities.js:194 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[fluent-ffmpeg]/lib/capabilities.js:194:9
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - async.js:52 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[async]/lib/async.js:52:16
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - async.js:1209 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[async]/lib/async.js:1209:30
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - capabilities.js:186 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[fluent-ffmpeg]/lib/capabilities.js:186:13
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - capabilities.js:123 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[fluent-ffmpeg]/lib/capabilities.js:123:9
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - async.js:52 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[async]/lib/async.js:52:16
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - async.js:1209 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[async]/lib/async.js:1209:30
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - capabilities.js:116 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[fluent-ffmpeg]/lib/capabilities.js:116:11
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - utils.js:223 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[fluent-ffmpeg]/lib/utils.js:223:16
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - which.js:68 F
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[which]/which.js:68:16
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - which.js:80 E
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[which]/which.js:80:29
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - which.js:89 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[which]/which.js:89:16
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - index.js:42 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[isexe]/index.js:42:5
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM:   - mode.js:8 
1:19:23 AM:     [repo]/[isexe]/mode.js:8:5
1:19:23 AM:   
1:19:23 AM: 
1:19:23 AM: not finished run queries - 4.168s
1:19:23 AM: not finished Generating image thumbnails - 4.111s
1:19:23 AM: (sharp:1520): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:19:23.397: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
1:19:23 AM: (sharp:1520): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:19:23.438: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
1:19:23 AM: Skipping functions preparation step: no functions directory set
1:19:23 AM: Caching artifacts
1:19:23 AM: Started saving node modules
1:19:23 AM: Finished saving node modules
1:19:23 AM: Started saving pip cache
1:19:23 AM: Finished saving pip cache
1:19:23 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
1:19:23 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
1:19:23 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
1:19:23 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
1:19:23 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
1:19:23 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
1:19:23 AM: Started saving go dependencies
1:19:23 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
1:19:27 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
1:19:27 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
1:19:27 AM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
1:19:27 AM: Finished processing build request in 1m15.231125909s
```

My `gatsby-config.js` file is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "#######",
    author: "#######"
  },
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-sass",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "images",
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`
      }
    },
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    "gatsby-transformer-ffmpeg",
    "gatsby-plugin-ffmpeg"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running `gatsby clean` to try to replicate the issue locally? Usually, if you're seeing it fail on Netlify but not locally you may have something cached either in `.cache` or `public` that is preventing the issue from cropping up. When Netlify build it will `npm install` ahead of the build, so if it is in your package it should pick it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netlify's build image [runs Ubuntu](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/03/14/a-more-flexible-build-architecture-with-updated-linux/), so you can probably install `ffmpeg` with the following command:

```sh
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

You can prepend this script to your Netlify build command, i.e

```
apt-get install ffmpeg && npm run build
```

or stick it as a new script in your `package.json`.

---

Instruction on building latest version of ffmpeg on Ubuntu: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks! I asked the Netlify community and they said to install the OS specific binary in the .cache folder beforehand or running a bash script as part of the build command.

I ended up using a different plugin that didn't require ffmpeg at all but I believe the method mentioned above is the correct solution in case anybody else runs into this issue.

Comment: ah those are good solution — I forgot about Netlify build plugin — you can very well build a plugin that'll pre-install ffmpeg before running the build script as well!

Comment: `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
4:56:32 AM: E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?` Seems this won't work without a sudo

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot use `apt-get install` to add additional dependencies to Netlify's build image. [This help article](https://answers.netlify.com/t/apt-get-install-build-dependency/3095) recommends downloading a static binary to work around this limitation.

The `fluent-ffmpeg` package (which is used by `gatsby-plugin-ffmpeg`) uses the environment variables `FFMPEG_PATH` and `FFPROBE_PATH` to find the executables it depends on.

I downloaded a static build of FFmpeg and added that to my gatsby project. I was then able to use the correct path for both the `FFMPEG_PATH` and `FFPROBE_PATH` variables, and added both to my Netlify build environment. This resolved my build errors.

- FFmpeg static builds: https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/
- `fluent-ffmpeg` environment variables: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#ffmpeg-and-ffprobe
- Adding env variables to Netlify builds: https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/